# Pasar una variable que tengo en php a una ventana modal

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

espero puedan ayudarme, me encuentro haciendo una tabla como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahorita si le doy el botón de editar me abre una modal, pero quiero que en la modal me arroje en los input los valores del renglón que se dio editar para realizar las modificaciones correspondientes. Este es mi código que me llena la tabla (Cabe mencionar que los datos los obtengo con AJAX):

```
<?php   
include ("config.php");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM servicios";
$registro = mysqli_query($db,$consulta);

$tabla = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($registro)){

    $editar = '<a href=\"php/EditService.php?a='.$row['NombreServicio'].'&b='.$row['Descripcion'].'&c='.$row['Precio'].'\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#MyModal\"  data-placement=\"top\" title=\"Editar\" class=\"btn btn-primary edit\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>';
    $eliminar = '<a href=\"php/DeleteService.php?id='.$row['idServicios'].'\" onclick=\"return confirm(\'¿Seguro que desea eliminiar este servicio?\')\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" title=\"Eliminar\" class=\"btn btn-danger\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>';        

    $tabla.='{

              "NombreServicio":"'.$row['NombreServicio'].'",
              "Descripcion":"'.$row['Descripcion'].'",
              "Precio":"'.$row['Precio'].'",
              "Acciones":"'.$editar. $eliminar.'"
            },';        
}   

$tabla = substr($tabla,0, strlen($tabla) - 1);

echo '{"data":['.$tabla.']}';
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la misma forma que cargas los datos de la tabla con AJAX, puedes pasar estos datos al hacer click en editar, a través de el identificador (ID) de cada fila. Con PHP esto no puedes hacerlo, necesitarás pasarlo con JavaScript.